# Angular: ERROR in Source file not found: '<file-path>'

Tags: angular

This error occurs only the second time angular development server is trying to compile after running `ng serve` (and resolves itself if you restart the process.)

I don't know what Angular is trying to say in that error message... What is wrong?

The file it's complaining about contains a single exported interface which is used in the app (and it works, after running `ng serve` again).

This is the same issue as described here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26437 but my file has an exported interface in it, so this does not explain why the problem occur, and I cannot just get rid of this file because it is used.

How can I solve this problem so it doesn't occur again and I wouldn't have to restart the angular development server every time it occurs?